# Why is the for loop running even though the condition is false

Tags: java, trace

I have been trying to write a code trace for this program. after many attempts on paper I thought I understood it but now I have stumbled again.

In the for loop `i=counter` ,because `i=0` and the `counter=0` so since it has to be less than counter how is this code even running?

I have included my incomplete code trace below.

The aim of the program is to print 50 unique random numbers between 1 and 999, in 10 rows of 5. The program works perfectly.I just want to figure out how its working with the help of a code trace. I know this might be a simple problem to you, but I am struggling with it. Could you please help me, thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Random50 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numbersNeeded = 50;
        int[] randomNumbers = new int[numbersNeeded];
        int counter = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int max = 999;
        int min = 1;

        while (counter < numbersNeeded) {

            int generated = min + randomGenerator.nextInt(max);

            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter && !found; i++) {

                if (randomNumbers[i] == generated) {

                    found = true;

                }

            }

            if (!found) {

                randomNumbers[counter++] = generated;

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

            System.out.printf("%03d ",randomNumbers[i] );

            if (i > 0 && (i+1) % 5 == 0) {

                System.out.println("");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code trace]

Comment: You’re incrementing counter in the while loop, so it won’t be zero by the time you get to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the reason why:

```
randomNumbers[counter++] = generated;
```

By using `counter++`, you're using the `++` postfix increment operator, which evaluates to the value of `counter`, but then increments it by 1 after the evaluation. The equivalent code without use of this operator would look something like this:

```
randomNumbers[counter] = generated;
counter = counter + 1;
```

So on the first iteration where this line is executed, `randomNumbers[0]` is updated, but then `counter` gets set to 1 (because 0 + 1 = 1). On the second iteration, `randomNumbers[1]` is updated, then `counter` gets updated to 2 (because 1 + 1 = 2)...and so forth.

You can find more information about arithmetic operators here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html